# What is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^3$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients

We know that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}=2^n$$
and that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2= \binom{2n}{n}$$
what about
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^3$$ ?

Comment: There is no "closed form" for this similar to the other two cases, but the sequence defined by it satisfies a three-term linear recurrence with polynomial coefficients. See http://oeis.org/A000172 .

Comment: Somewhat remarkably, $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \left({n \atop i}\right)^{\!3}$ *does* have a known closed form (which is rather tricky to derive).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies which is...?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  $$12\,{\frac {\sin \left( \pi \, \left( n+1 \right)/2  \right) 
\Gamma  \left( 3\,n/2 \right) }{ \left( \Gamma  \left( n/2 \right) 
 \right) ^{3}{n}^{2}}}
$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე $0$ is $n$ is odd, otherwise $(-1)^{n/2} \binom{3n/2}{n/2,n/2,n/2}$. This is known as "Dixon's identity", and can be generalized as $\sum_{k=-a}^a(-1)^k{a+b\choose a+k} {b+c\choose b+k}{c+a\choose c+k}  = \frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$. Although the original proofs were quite technical, there are at least 2 combinatorial proofs by Foata (see http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~foata/paper/ProbComb.pdf, page 37 and http://tube.sfu-kras.ru/video/396?playlist=397 at 39:30). The shortest proofs are still the algebraic ones, for example by MachMahon's master theorem or Dyson's conjecture.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of summation can be done using Gosper-type algorithms, see the [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) book by Petkovšek, Wilf and Zeilberger. The algorithms are built into Mathematica, so if you run

```
Table[k -> Sum[Binomial[n, i]^k, {i, 0, n}], {k, 0, 5}] // TableForm
```

you get

\begin{align*}
 0&\to n+1 \\
 1&\to 2^n \\
 2&\to \binom{2 n}{n} \\
 3&\to \, _3F_2(-n,-n,-n;1,1;-1) \\
 4&\to \, _4F_3(-n,-n,-n,-n;1,1,1;1) \\
 5&\to \, _5F_4(-n,-n,-n,-n,-n;1,1,1,1;-1) \\
\end{align*}

The hypergeometric functions $_kF_m$ appearing in the result are documented under the name [`HypergeometricPFQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html) in Mathematica. Since these are just rephrasing the original sum, the algorithm is telling us that there is no closed-form solution expressible as a rational function.

Comment: Actually these ${}_kF_m$ representations are pretty close to direct transcriptions of the summation, i.e. by definition
$$ {}_3F_2(-n,-n,-n;1,1;-1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!} \dfrac{\text{pochhammer}(-n,k)^3}{\text{pochhammer}(1,k)^2}$$
and the  term for $k$ turns out to be ${n \choose k}^3$ for $0 \le k \le n$, $0$ for $k > n$.

Comment: I am not sure this is a good example for the power of that algorithm, since I think (but might be wrong) really nothing much happens here and this is a renaming basically.

Comment: In Mathematica, the command FullSimplify[Sum[Binomial[n, i]^3, {i, 0, n}]] returns HypergeometricPFQ[{-n, -n, -n}, {1, 1}, -1]

Comment: The algorithm is telling you that there is no closed form in terms of rational functions. Of course, the hypergeometric functions are just a dressing -- but so is the binomial symbol for $k = 2$.

Comment: If this was your point may I propose a different phrasing of the first sentence 'This sort of summation can be done [...]' suggests (to me) some actual success. By analogy, it is relevant information when Risch' algorthm does not produce an antiderivative for a function, yet to say this integeration can be done using Risch' algorthm seems misleading to me in such a case.

Comment: @quid: better now?

Comment: It seems more transparent to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

These are called the **Franel Numbers**
As Michael noted, see [oeis.org/A000172](http://oeis.org/A000172) for a summary of known facts and references...